# How to access Knative build logs on minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, knative

I installed Knative on minikube using the [instructions from Knative's documentation](https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/master/install/Knative-with-Minikube.md). Then I tried to get their [Springboot build example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/knative-build-tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot) running.

How do I see the logs?  It says to use "logs jib", but I tried `kubectl logs jib` and `minikube logs jib` and didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: if anyone could tag this `knative` and `knative-build`, I would appreciate it! Not enough reputation to create tags...

Comment: use `logs jib-cache`